# Calling a PHP script to get image urls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My path is like this

/website/php
/website/javascript
/website/photographer/index.html
/website/photographer/photos

I have a javascript which displays a photo gallery for the photos in the folder. Using ajax with jquery, it calls a PHP file that returns the image urls in "photos" so that the javascript can then set up the gallery, etc.

The problem is that I can't seem to get PHP to access the "photos" folder. See, I have a bunch of different photographer pages which do the same thing, so I'm trying to have one PHP file and one javascript file, but different directories.

The method I devised was to send "window.location.pathname" in the ajax get call so that php can get the directory the current page is in, and then simply search the "photos" folder in that directory.

```
chdir($_GET["currentPath"] . "photos"); //change the directory so we just get the file names
echo json_encode(glob("*.jpg"));
```

I get this error: 
Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in /hermes/bosweb/web054/b541/ipg.danielechevarriacom/testing/oneonethousand_test/php/images.php on line 4
[]

And when I

```
echo $_GET["currentPath"] . "photos";
```

It prints: "/testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/photos"

That is the correct directory where the photos are, so I don't know why this isn't working. I am assuming this has to do with how chdir works.

I don't want to do chdir("../steele/photos") because I will have many directories and I want to have the PHP file stay general. I just want to be able for javascript to tell php where the current directory is and then PHP switches to that directory. Why doesn't this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Judging by the answers, maybe I am going about this wrong? How does one suggest I organize my directories without duplicating lots of code?

Comment: I think your directories are just fine. In my opinion javascript is not needed for this gallery. Simply get the list of files in the photo directory and output them with php.

Answer (score 0):

First off, NEVER trust the variables in $_GET/$_POST/etc. Using your script, I could potentially list out file in any directory *on the server* (including non-web-accessible ones), not just the ones you want.

It doesn't work because the path in $_GET["currentPath"] is the URL, not the folder name: it's set to "http://danielechevarria.com/testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/" instead of "steele".

Change the variable sent by the JavaScript to just be the top-level path (such as "steele") and consider changing your script to be something like this:

```
//Validate the path somehow, in this case, reject anything that's not alphanumeric
if(!preg_match("/^\w+$/", $_GET["currentPath"])) die("{'error':'Invalid path'}");
chdir("../" . $_GET["currentPath"] . "/photos");
echo json_encode(glob("*.jpg"));
```

Comment: But I don't want to send "steele" because I want this script to work for any photographer page - I don't want to use a different javascript for each directory. I just want javascript to send the current directory of the page to php and then php get the photo folder in that directory. "window.location.pathname" only sends the whole pathname.

Comment: Assuming only a single depth to the artist directories, you could use `var currentPath = window.location.pathname.match(/\w+$/)[0];` on the JS side

Answer (score 0):

chdir requires a file system path, not an http path.

Based on the output of the echo command, it looks like it is passing the whole http url ("http://danielechevarria.com/testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/photos")  to the chdir function.

Comment: Okay, but "window.location.pathname" sends the http path. As far as I know, there is no javascript function that sends the current path of an arbitrary relative position... that would be nice.

Comment: if  you know the docroot path, then you could generate the absolute path in php from the javascript path that is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe chdir only works on local paths, not web paths. So, in order to "chdir" to the photos directory, you need the FULL system path.

i.e. /home/user/public_html/photos or C:\www\photos

https://www.php.net/chdir

Here's my input: No idea why you are using ajax and javascript to pull in images and build a gallery. Why not just use PHP to generate the gallery? Javascript over complicates this.

Comment: So how do I use javascript to send the current relative path?

Comment: You don't. You use php, what you are doing in your current code would work, but you aren't using the correct path to access the photos. Its probably looking for photos in a directory like this.. /hermes/bosweb/web054/b541/ipg.danielechevarriacom/testing/oneonethousand_test/php/http://danielechevarria.com/testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/photos .. which is ridiculous

Comment: I made a mistake. What its passing now is /testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/photos but I still get the same error.

Comment: Right, and what you are doing is attempting to change directory to that exact directory on your server. I'm guessing when you ssh to the machine, and type "cd /testing" it tells you that the testing directory doesn't exist.

Comment: try using getcwd() to build the directory path for the images. http://us2.php.net/getcwd

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl in php to call 
("http://danielechevarria.com/testing/ oneonethousand_test/steele/photos")

Comment: That seems way more work than necessary. Why can't I just access "/testing/oneonethousand_test/steele/photos"?